# get valueprovider from vaadin grid column in vaadin 24

Tags: vaadin, deprecated, vaadin-grid, value-provider

I'm working on a project that exports vaadin grid data to excel. To get the data from the grid cells, the `column.getRenderer().getValueProviders()` method is used, similar to how it's done [in this addon](https://github.com/FlowingCode/GridExporterAddon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flowingcode/vaadin/addons/gridexporter/GridExporter.java).
Renderer.getValueProviders() was [deprecated in vaadin 23.1](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.3.14/deprecated-list.html) and does not exist in vaadin 24.

Is there a way to get the values from a cell in vaadin 24?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a "direct" method to do that.

You would need to use reflection:

```
protected <X> ValueProvider<T, X> getValueProvider(final Grid.Column<T> column)
{
    final Renderer<T> r = column.getRenderer();
    if(r instanceof BasicRenderer)
    {
        try
        {
            final Method getValueProvider = BasicRenderer.class.getDeclaredMethod("getValueProvider");
            getValueProvider.setAccessible(true);
            return (ValueProvider<T, X>)getValueProvider.invoke(r);
        }
        catch(final IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
                    | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e)
        {
            // Something went wrong, but it's not our place to say what or why.
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

See:

https://github.com/xdev-software/vaadin-grid-exporter/blob/develop/vaadin-grid-exporter/src/main/java/software/xdev/vaadin/grid_exporter/grid/GridDataExtractor.java
and
https://github.com/FlowingCode/GridExporterAddon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flowingcode/vaadin/addons/gridexporter/GridExporter.java

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Note: in my case, I needed to check for other types of Renderers (apart from BasicRenderer), as is done in the linked repository.